# getting image from email

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I've noticed that when someone copy paste an email and then sends it the "src" value of the images changes. For example if the original email has an image which is an attachment and its contentId is: cid:companlyLogo. And then someone copy paste this email into a new draft and sends it this src value changes to: src="cid:image001.jpg@01CCF6B1.A4CA2FE0".

I have no clue whatsoever on how to get this image and save it in an image object in c#. Am currently using EWS api for doing this. Problem is that since its a copy paste it no longer has attachments as the original email.

Does anyone has any idea on how to retrieve the images of this types of emails?

Answer (score 4):

Embedded images are treated as email attachments by Exchange.  That means you can retrieve the images from the [`Item.Attachments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.attachments%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property.  The following example shows you how to do this using the EWS Managed API.  Notice that EWS will not load the attachments unless you explicitly tell it to by calling [`LoadPropertiesForItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.loadpropertiesforitems%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

You can tell that an attachment is embedded by checking the [`Attachment.IsInline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment.isinline%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property.  EWS lets you load the attachment and save it to disk by calling the [`FileAttachment.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634091%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) method.

```
ExchangeService service = GetService();
var view = new ItemView(1);
var searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, "Some subject text");
var items = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));

var item = items.ElementAt(0) as EmailMessage;

for (int i = 0; i < item.Attachments.Count; i++)
{
    var att = item.Attachments[i] as FileAttachment;
    if (att.IsInline && att.ContentType.Contains("image"))
    {
        att.Load(String.Format(@"c:\temp\attachedimage_{0}.jpg", i));
    }
}
```