# Retrieve and display inline images from email when encoded as a CID with Ruby on Rails

Tags: email, url, outlook, inline, attachment

I'm using [Viewpoint](https://github.com/zenchild/Viewpoint) to retrieve email from an Exchange server for creation of objects in a Ruby on Rails app.

I'm able to see that an image has been included, inline, in the body of an email, like so:

```
<img src=\"cid:94C552FB-8474-437C-AB44-DDF809047AB9\" type=\"image/png\">
```

And I can see an attachments node in the item blob, too:

```
:attachments=>{
  :file_attachment=>{
    :content_type=>{
      :text=>"image/png"
    },
    :content_id=>{
      :text=>"94C552FB-8474-437C-AB44-DDF809047AB9"
    },
    :attachment_id=>{
      :id=>"AAMkAGEzNmExNzEzLTcxMjEtNDM5YS04NmE0LWE0NWU3MWZiMjEwNgBGAAAAAAB4VZcbdHrATrbGrKL0ANCfBwCjSVkOjPEtQoJN3xOKeIYJAAzyZ5e9AACjSVkOjPEtQoJN3xOKeIYJAA25w05NAAABEgAQAK9ad+6BP7VHru83AO7CTrU="
    },
    :name=>{
      :text=>"Hollowbody 2.png"
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how do I turn any of this into a URL suitable for use as the src of an img tag? I've seen answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499904/getting-image-from-email), but they appear to have special privileges in that

1. They're running in C#, which has special understanding of Exchange and the way it handles resource (I assume)
2. They appear to be running on the same server as Exchange, and have access to the same tmp directory where attachments are held.

If you're on another machine in another language, how do you get to these images? I know it's possible, since there are email clients on everything from mobile phones to refrigerators that can receive emails from Exchange/Outlook and render the image…